# Multiple sequence alignment for general strings java

Tags: java, hadoop, sequence

I'm working in hadoop and I must align n strings in java and i want an algorithm which compute general strings (no bioinformatics, genome, etc) in Java. Es.

```
ASFHASFHASDSAAPJEIHRA <-- seq1
AAPSOFHASFDSOISISN--A <-- seq2
AWP-JWRAIADSDIA--N--A <-- seq3
AOPSJD-A-JDSSDSOQOSSJ <-- seq4
100000000011000000000 <-- score
```

There's someone can help me for a name, library or something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite get it. What do you mean by "compute general strings"?Thank you.

Comment: make multiple sequence alignment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own dynamic programming algorithm, but the complexity is: O(N^k) if N is the sequence length and k the number of sequences. Suppose you have k=2 sequences:
The you have a 2D grid where each point in your grid corresponds to a pair of characters. So position (1,1) corresponds to word1[1] and word2[1]. Horizontal and vertical edges in this grid correspond to insertions and deletions, while diagonal ones are matches or mismatches. For each you have to device a penalty. In your example a match = +1 while the other possibilities are +0. When you arrive at the bottom right of the grid you have the optimal alignment score.

Comment: thanks @irW, sorry for my late reply. I've solved with Levenshtein distance and a phylogenetic tree :)

Comment: Yes, that's how most aligners work (I think Clustal works like this). The bruteforce aligner is not recommended for large sequences. The levenshtein distance is actually calculated using my explanation (using the 2D grid -> dynamic programming).